# Accessing parent applet from inner class

Tags: java, oop, applet

I was wondering if anyone could let me know how to access an object from my main (applet) class from an object I created within the main (applet) class.  The source might clarify things a little.  Normally I would use accessors but this is for the sake of simplicity

```
public class Bravo  {

  int copyint;

  Bravo()  {

    // Here I want to access the targetobj's theint from here
    copyint = targetobj.theint;  // I belive this doesn't work 
  }
}

public class Charlie  {

  static int theint;

  Charlie() {

    theint = 7;
  }
}

public class alpha extends JApplet {

  public void init() {

    createApp();
  }

  public void createApp()  {

     Charlie targetobj = new Charlie();
     Bravo askingobj = new Bravo();
  }
}
```

TYIA
-Roland

Comment: _I belive this doesn't work_ what happened when you try to compile?

Comment: This was off the top of my head but I really doubt this would work in it's present state

Comment: You can see my answer below, this should work.

Comment: Is there any reason not to add a Charlie argument to the Bravo constructor, and pass targetObj to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See `static int theint` you have declared it as a static. So you need not use object to access this variable. You can just use `className.variable`, like this:

```
Charlie.theint;
```

This would work, provided class is visible to other class.

Comment: Ok my example was wrong I will repost something that reflects my problem more accuratly... unless it's as simple as that.  Hmm tyvm but I will have to repost